# Block Button Click on Refresh Page

Tags: asp.net

Am new to `ASP.NET`. My application have third party control and button. when page load i add 3 columns and remove columns in button click but if i refresh the page both action fired together.

So i searched i find one Answer here. That is Redirect to same page. After add this code nothing happen in button click also what am doing wrong here? how achive the solution?

**My Code: ASP.NET**

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles Me.Load

        grdVersions.ActiveSheetView.Columns.Add(3, 3)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) 
    Handles btn1.Click
        grdVersions.ActiveSheetView.Columns.Remove(4, 2)
        Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx")
    End Sub
```

Am using `visual studio 2008`.

Answer (score 0):

In your page load method check for the flag postback

```
If Not IsPostBack
    grdVersions.ActiveSheetView.Columns.Add(3, 3)
End If
```

Comment: sorry for late reply.. Now also nothing happen